# Should comments that spoil a puzzle be flagged for mod attention?

Tags: discussion, spoilers, comments

The comment: [Thanks, dad! Never again](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78260/thanks-dad-never-again#comment229256_78260)

Is a big spoiler for the puzzle in the question, I immediately made to flag for mod attention, but couldn't find whether spoiler comments/answers should be flagged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no hard-and-fast rule about this, but people generally try to keep spoilers out of the comments, especially on a question (on an answer, I think it's fair to assume that if you're reading the comments, you've also read the answer).

The two strategies that are employed are either to comment vaguely enough that your comment can only be understood by someone who already knows the solution (e.g *I think the third word should have the last two letters reversed*), or use ROT13 to encrypt your comment so that it can't be read at a casual glance.

It doesn't hurt to flag the comment.  I've deleted the comment in question here.

Comment: One exception to the "don't worry all that much about spoilers when commenting on an answer" rule-of-thumb is when the question and answer are both very short. In this case, the comment fits on the same page with the question, and it's visible for people viewing the question for the first time. As the last thing on the page, it has a good chance of drawing attention by its position alone.